# How can I add @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator to Cypress.io Commands?

Tags: cypress

I'm getting this error when I run my cypress tests.

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator (https://git.io/vb4Se) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. while parsing file: ../cypress/support/commands/commands.js

I added the plugin to .babelrc but it's not working.

Comment: Do you have a repo with your setup? It works for me with adding to list in `plugins` of `.babelrc`. You also need to have something like https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-webpack-preprocessor setup.